# Is there a way to prevent javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in Unity because server does not support SSLv3 to prevent poodle attack?

Tags: ssl, unity-game-engine, https

There's sometimes that www class in Unity return an error as

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7a819eb0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x56aff990:0x00000000)
```

I assumed that www class use SSLv3 which server did not support this so, it appeared this error.

Is there a way to config www class behavior to use TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2 instead? It's strange that this error happen only sometimes, not always. Sometimes I also got `java.io.FileNotFoundException: <my_url>` in the same time that SSL error occurred too.

Comment: You could try replacing your use of the WWW class with the experimental [UnityWebRequest class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Networking.UnityWebRequest.html). I don't know if you can specify TLS, but it may not give you the error.

Comment: Any code we can take a look at?

Comment: @ejsd1989 Juse call normal "WWW www = new WWW(<my_https_url>);" Nothing special.

Comment: We're having the same problem after disabling SSLv3 on the server. Unity is struggling with TLSv1, but only on the Android app. iOS works fine. Would love a solution!

Answer (score 1):

*Sometimes* the www class returns the error

'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException'

Try to use a different http client and see if you can reproduce this error.  There are several reasons you could be getting this error and you have not articulated why you believe this is due to the server not supporting TLS 1.1/1.2.  So here are the steps I would take to solve this problem:

1) make sure to use the -Djavax.net.debug=all (or whichever verbose logging flag you can use) flag to get verbose logging messages.  These can be critical for solving subtle SSL bugs.  This flag should provide verbose logging regarding the handshake including cipher suite and SSL version negotiation.

2) You can use openssl s_client -connect server.com:443 -ssl3 to determine if the server supports ssl3.  Try different versions to see what the server supports.

3) IMPORTANT.  If your client does not support SNI and the server supports SNI- you will get this error message.  This is why I suggest trying different HTTP clients (make sure at least one of them supports SNI) and check whether or not SNI is the cause of your problem.

Good luck.

Comment: It's clearly stated that "error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure" and the server is my own server which is disable sslv3 due to prevent poodle so, I'm sure of it.